Bundle LESS into Single File using Rollup
I have a React component that is bundled using Rollup.js. This library also includes styling written in LESS. I am already able to create a single compiled CSS file from that using the PostCSS plugin.
However, I would prefer to provide a bundled LESS file instead of CSS so that it is still possible to modify the styling using variables etc. The LESS file would then be imported by the application that uses this library and compiled there.
Is there a way to do that?
My current Rollup.js config is this:
import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import packageJson from './package.json' assert { type: 'json' };
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import postCss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';

/**
 * @type {import('rollup').RollupOptions[]}
 */
export default [
    {
        input: './index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.main,
                format: 'cjs',
                sourcemap: true,
            },
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'esm',
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            peerDepsExternal(),
            nodeResolve(),
            commonjs(),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' }),
            postCss({ extract: 'style.css' }),
            terser(),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: './index.ts',
        plugins: [dts({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json' })],
        output: {
            file: packageJson.types,
            format: 'esm',
        },
        external: [/\.css$/, /\.less$/],
    },
];

In theory, all I would need is a way to tell postCss() to please not compile the LESS files.
